# mongoid versioning can't destroy just one single version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, versioning

I'm using Mongoid::Versioning to version my Wiki model by including Mongoid::Versioning

```
class Wiki
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title
  field :content
  field :summary
  # ...
end
```

I want to restore a wiki document to a previous version, for instance I have a wiki which version is up to 3, and I then want to restore it to version 2, how do I remove corresponding versions embedded by Mongoid::Versioning(in this case version 2)? I have tried common ways to remove a embedded document, but it seems that it either does nothing or clear all the versions embedded in my document.

Answer (score 1):

```
version_to_delete = wiki.versions[1]
wiki.versions.delete(version_to_delete)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770616/mongoidversioning-delete-one-version/26776813#26776813) for more details.