# Mongoid::Versioning - delete one version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I've a Rails model set up with Mongoid::Versioning.

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  include Mongoid::Versioning

  field :name, type: String
end
```

I want to delete a specific older version. For eg.

```
post = Post.create name: 'A'
post.update_attributes name: 'B'
post.update_attributes name: 'C'
post.version #=> 3
post.versions.count #=> 2
first_version = post.versions.first #=> #<Post _id: , created_at: _, updated_at: _, version: 2, name: "B">
```

I want to delete `first_version`, but when I try to delete it..

```
first_version.delete
post.versions.count #=> 1
post.reload
post.versions.count #=> 0
```

..all versions get deleted.

I've tried using `destroy` instead, tried running the code inside a block passed to `post.versionless`, to no avail. What should I do?

*UPDATE*:
I've gotten it to work with `Mongoid::Paranoia`. But it'd be nice to have the flexibility of not using `Mongoid::Paranoia`.

Comment: You should include which version of Mongoid you are using. FWIW Mongoid::Versioning is deprecated and will be removed in 4.0.0

Comment: Mongoid 4, but I'm using Versioning via the mongoid-versioning gem (which brings back the removed functionality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of deleting intermediate versions is incorrect and corrupts the case for versioning. If you delete intermediate versions, then you are never sure if it's intentional or some corruption.

In spite of this, if you *really* want to do this, you should change to code to the following.

```
deleted = post.versions.first
post.versions.delete(deleted)
```

I am not sure why you want to do this though. If you want to ensure that you don't have too many versions and want to clean up, use `max_versions` class method.

```
Post.max_versions(5)
```

If you want to avoid versioning in some cases, use `versionless`

```
post.versionless(&:save)
```

Comment: The actual model that we have stores zipped attachments. Users need the ability to upload multiple versions of these zipped attachments and need the ability to clean out older versions if they clutter up the model.
We are not as concerned about maintaing a progressive diff, so don't care about history getting mucked up because we deleted intermediate versions.

Comment: @Vighnesh it sounds like you want to maintain a set of documents and allow deletes and inserts. Why the need to version at all?